# C# version of VB.Net code, tried converters but they are failing with NonModuleDeclaration

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to write a service call for to interact with an API and all the documentation is in VB.Net, a language I do not know. I have been able to use code converters to convert from VB.Net to C# with no problems until I tried to convert a code snippet just now.

```
Public Function Execute(ByVal lookupMethod as string, ByVal lookupParameters as List(Of LookupServicesSvc.LookupParameter), session as Guid) as LookupData
```

That is the VB.Net code I am trying to figure out and I have tried 3 different convertsers but they all return the error `line 1 col 8: invalid NonModuleDeclaration`

I don't know why they are failing, I am assuming because it is a small snippet there is other code missing, but if anyone can give me an idea of what the C# equivalent for this is I would appreciate it.

EDIT:
Please note that this is the entire code given to me by the documentation. As I stated, I presume there is something missing, but as I don't know VB.Net I can not guess as to what that missing code would be. The missing code was explained in a comment and I appreciate that as it will be helpful in the feature.

Comment: When I used the Telerik [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/), I had to put in the `End Function` line to get it to work.

Comment: Either you forgot to include the "End Function" statement or you are attempting to convert a single statement in an Interface Block.  You have to give a converter semi-valid code to get a conversion.

Comment: @LarsTech I figured there was something missing but I don't know enough about VB.net to hazard a guess. Thank you for the information though. I will keep it in mind if I have to convert another snippet list this.

Comment: @TnTinMn That was the entire code given in the documentation so I had no idea what might have been missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public LookupData Execute(string lookupMethod, 
    List<LookupServicesSvc.LookupParameter> lookupParameters, Guid session) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your issue was.

A quick visit to converter.telerik.com and completing the function declaration resulted in the following:

```
public LookupData Execute(string lookupMethod, List<LookupServicesSvc.LookupParameter> lookupParameters, Guid session) {

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

Comment: The key words in your answer are "completing the function". I don't know VB.Net so I did not know how to complete it or if anything was missing. That was the code, in it's entirety, as given in the documentation.

Comment: If you know C#, it can almost be implied you know VB, as they're both basically the same language, with just with different syntaxes.
In any case, they've done the same as any other documentation website: They showed the method (head) declaration.

Comment: @Beatsleigher not true there is a multitude of differences unrelated to syntax. I could probably list a hundred or so.